# How can I ensure punctuation as access-keys are read correctly by screenreaders like JAWS?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

Suppose a link has access key of "Alt + . "

```
<a  title=" some content (Alt+.)"> some content </a>
```

The problem with screen readers is that they will interpret the . or , as long or short pauses and don't actually inform screen-reader users of the punctuation mark. This is in default JAWS setting of "most" for verbosity of punctuation.

I thought of changing the `Alt + .` as `Alt + . (dot)`. But that will read out the '(' and ')' as well.

changing the `Alt + .` as `Alt + . dot` works fine for screen reader users, but the tool-tip will become confusing as it sees `Alt + . dot`

How do we fix this? JAWS setting should not be changed from "most" to "all". This workaround is not accepted.

Comment: Does it *have* to be in the `title`? Wouldn’t it be possible to include in the actual element content?

Comment: No. It's not possible since the content is an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the text to precisely the way you want it announced. For example:

```
<a  title=" some content (Alt+.)" aria-label="some content (Alt plus period)"> some content </a>
```

Comment: This will affect the tooltip. Also, this will not be consistent with other access keys.
If the other access keys are Alt + ; they will also need to be edited.

Comment: I modified it to address your concerns. However, relying on a title as a tooltip (without additional support like jQuery-UI tooltips) will not be accessible to keyboard-only users.

Comment: Yes. I understand. My concerns were primarily on that to make something better readable for screen readers shouldn't affect other users like keyboard-only users.